# Do I need to periodically re-submit my sitemaps to yahoo/bing?

Tags: seo, sitemap

I know Google's webmasters downloads a new version of my sitemaps every day. I am not sure if the yahoo / bing systems do the same thing. Google's says "Downloaded" and for the sitemaps that add the daily content they are downloaded on a daily basis. But the Last Submitted date on Yahoo site explorer is just the date of when I originally linked them into yahoo.

There is nothing I see to suggest Yahoo is rechecking my submitted sitemaps, particularly since my page index count seems to go down.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yahoo is [now powered by Bing](http://www.ysearchblog.com/2010/08/17/latest-on-the-yahoo-and-microsoft-search-alliance), so you can forget about Y!
2. There's nothing in the Bing Webmaster tools console to advise when the last crawl/read of the XML Sitemap took place.

...which leaves you having to check your own server logs.

Alternatively, *and I have no evidence to back this up*, you could ensure that your XML sitemap file is referenced in your robots.txt file to ensure it gets "noticed".

Comment: Bing does index sitemaps, though there are [reports](http://www.bing.com/community/webmaster/f/12251/p/648012/9540745.aspx) of Bing passing over compressed sitemap files.

Comment: Actually I had a Bing account, and then created a Yahoo account, since making the Yahoo account all indexing on Bing has gone to zero, but Yahoo reports 40 pages indexed.

Comment: @danlefree there was no suggestion that Bing doesn't index sitemaps, just the question of how often they are revisited :)